# What does "forward-only access" mean exactly?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm looking at classes to use to read a large xml file. A fast implementation of the C# XmlReader class, XmlTextReader, provides "forward-only access." What does this mean?

Comment: What's another direction a reader could go?

Comment: It means you can only go forward, not backward, just as it says. You can only go forward; you can't back up. What else could "forward-only" possibly mean?

Comment: @KenWhite to some extent it is hard to define what "forward-only" means for tree structure like XML... does it mean you go to deepest child and stop? Clearly that would be very strange behavior for reading files... but how else you define "forward" in a tree? Why my parent->next sibling is "forward" while "parent" is backward? (Indeed documentation means "forward in a file" - but that may not be obvious)

Comment: It means that, when the reader is positioned at an XML node, you cannot access content from prior nodes in the XML stream, either by "rewinding" the reader, or by accessing some DOM information that the reader might have kept for you.  If you need information about some prior parent node as you process a later node, you must save that information yourself.  Note however that attributes of an element are considered part of the element node itself and can all be accessed when the reader is positioned on the element.

Comment: Every time you read a node it advances to the next node until there are no more nodes. It's like a `SqlDataReader`. Every time you call `Read` it goes to the next record. There's no way to ask for the previous record again. The `Reader` part of the name in common suggests that you wouldn't use it to manipulate or analyze the data. You would just use it to get the data. In that scenario where you're only reading it there's no reason to go back.

Comment: It's probably worth understanding *why* such a thing exists: a forward-only reader can be implemented to be very fast and use very little memory, even on enormous documents. If you have a scenario where you need to read very large XML documents and you can accomplish it it in a forward-only style, you should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"forward-only" means just that - you can only go forward through data. The main benefits of such approach are no need to store previous information (leading to low memory usage) and ability to  read from non-seekable sources like TCP stream (where you can't *seek* back unlike with file stream that allow random access).

"Forward-only" is very easy to see for table-based structures (like reading from database) - "forward-only" reader will let you only check "current" record or move to the next row. There will be no way to access data from already seen rows via such reader (you have to save data outside of reader to be able to access it).

For XmlReader it is slightly more confusing as it produces tree structure out of stream of text. From stream reading point of view "forward-only" means you will not be able to get any data that reader already looked at (like root node that is basically first line of the file or parent node of current one as it had to be earlier in the file).

But from XML tree generation point of view "forward-only" may be confusing - it produces *elements* in depth-first order (because that how they are present in the text of the XML) meaning that "next" element is not necessary the one you'd like to see  in the tree (especially if you expect breadth-first access like "names of all authors of this book").

Note that XmlReader allows you to access all *attributes* of current node at any time as it considers them part of the "current element".